# PHP POST Referrer

Tags: post, paypal, referrer

I am implementing a PayPal IPN page and would like to check to ensure that requests are truly coming from PayPal and not being spoofed.
I would assume that HTTP_REFERRER would not be a good way of checking?
I've tried this approach and the variable just comes up empty.

Is there a way to check where a post is coming from? Maybe in the HTTP request header?

And a related side note. From a security standpoint how reliable would this method be?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That would be completely unreliable, as someone could spoof the Referer field as easily as they could spoof the request.

What you need to do is use PayPal's documented IPN validation protocol, which involves posting the IPN notification back to PayPal with cmd=_notify-validate. See the [PayPal IPN documentation](https://cms.paypal.com/us/cgi-bin/?cmd=_render-content&content_ID=developer/e_howto_admin_IPNIntro) for details.

Answer (score 1):

This variable has a spelling error, actually it's spelled `$_SERVER['HTTP_REFERER']`. So, make sure you are checking it right.

From the security point of view, this is totally fakeable, so don't rely only it.

Answer (score 1):

PayPal attaches a `verify_sign` to all IPN posts.

[PayPal IPN Docs](https://cms.paypal.com/cms_content/US/en_US/files/developer/IPNGuide.pdf)